# Integration test with Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, ninject, integration-testing, t4

I am familiar with the fact, that i should not use dependency injection in unit tests, so i can unit test each layer independently.

Still, I want to create integration tests for my controllers. Therefore I need to inject my repositories into the Controllers from a unit test.

I a following a generic approach using a T4 script, that creates a test class for each controller, containing a test method for each ActionResult. This test method should simply call the method to make sure no exceptions are thrown to the surface.

Because of using this T4 script, I cannot manually feed the repositories into the controllers. I need to make use of dependency injection.

Based on my former experience, this should work, but i keep getting the error:

```
Unable to get default constructor for class <<UnitTest>>
```

My generated classes look like this at the moment:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestControllersHomeController
{
    private EL.NET.Web.Controllers.HomeController c;
    //setup
    public TestControllersHomeController(Project.Controllers.HomeController c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }
    [ClassInitialize]
    public void ClassInitialize()
    {

        var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.CreatePublicKernel();
        kernel.Bind<TestControllersHomeController>().ToSelf();
        kernel.Bind<Project.Controllers.HomeController>().ToSelf();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndex()
    {
        var result = c.Index();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Edit:

I already found out, that the repositories can be loaded with help of the GetService() method of IKernel. But for the Membership provider, this doesn't work. 
Again, I do not want to mock the provider, I want to perform an integration test so I know if my Controller methods throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit test must have a default constructor:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestControllersHomeController
{
    private HomeController _sut;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void MyTestInitialize() 
    {
        var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.CreatePublicKernel();
        _sut = kernel.Resolve<HomeController>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndex()
    {
        var result = _sut.Index();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The non-generic method 'Ninject.Syntax.IResolutionRoot.Resolve(Ninject.Activation.IRequest)' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: @ckonig Use the `Get<T>` extension method instead of Resolve. So the `kernel.Get<HomeController>();` call should work and don't forget to add the `using Ninject;`

Comment: What worked for this specific situation was the GetService() method of IKernel. Now i am struggling with resolving the Custom Membership Provider

Comment: Yeah sure i know we arent supposed to DI in tests but man when you have to implement it in existing code this snippet helps :)